# getting the slave buildserver to work all the way

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I have a 32 bits xp machine that has been building our builds for a year now without much problem, now we have a new demand on our environment. The consultancy firm involved have some software that only thrives on 64bit 2008 webserver. So I set up a slave buildserver on the webserver so that their integration tests would work.

Now I have it up and running - we had trouble with useraccounts, having logfiles in the program files folder, and other stuff but it is running now and builds when a change is detected.

BUT:
I can´t administrate the slave from cctray - when I click force build on a project I get this message:
[image]

and I have no clue as to why, the webdashboard is a bit more informative:

`ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Remote.CommunicationsException: Request processing has failed on the remote server: Key cannot be null. Parameter name: key at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Remote.CruiseServerClient.ValidateResponse(Response response) at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Remote.CruiseServerClient.ListBuildParameters(String projectName) at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.WebDashboard.ServerConnection.ServerAggregatingCruiseManagerWrapper.ListBuildParameters(IProjectSpecifier projectSpecifier, String sessionToken) at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.WebDashboard.Dashboard.ProjectParametersAction.Execute(ICruiseRequest cruiseRequest) at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.WebDashboard.MVC.Cruise.CruiseActionProxyAction.Execute(IRequest request) at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.WebDashboard.MVC.Cruise.ExceptionCatchingActionProxy.Execute(IRequest request)`

:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is some kind of bug i ccnet on 64-bits clients- you can get it to work more or less but not as beautifully as on 32...
but thats the price of progress I guess